# Single Ruby/Rails method to check an object both exists and has an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Before I start littering my code with an unwieldy method of my own creation, I'm wondering if there's an existing Ruby/Rails method that will:

- Returns true if @foo exists and @foo has an ID (e.g. you're in the foo#show)
- Returns false if @foo exists but does not yet have an ID (e.g. you're in foo#new)
- Returns false if @foo does not exist (e.g. you're in bar#index)

I've tried to search the API docs but the terms I'm using are by necessity so general (ID, save, exists, etc) that I've not found anything so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

```
@foo.try(:id)
```

will return id or nil.

If you strictly want true or false,

```
!!@foo.try(:id)
```

Comment: for the second case 'try method' is redundant, enough with !!@foo.id

Answer (score 0):

For first 2, use `!@foo.new_record?` new_record? method returns true/false if model was saved to database and have id or not.

For third, read this: [defined?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F)